# Modify base class in virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following code, in the virtual function of the derived class, how can I invoke the same function in the base class to modify the base class?

```
class Base{
 public:
   int a;
   virtual Base & operator +=(Base const & rhs)
   { 
     a += rhs.a; 
     return *this;
   }
};

class Derived: public Base{
 public:
   int b;
   virtual Derived & operator +=(Derived const & rhs)
   { 
     // What should I write to invoke the += in Base class?
     // something like Base::+=(rhs.Base);
     b += rhs.b;
     return *this;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add:

```
Base::operator+=(rhs);
```

to call base version.

Comment: This makes sense. But I wonder why I can not omit the word `operator` and write `Base::+= rhs.Base;`

Comment: @Allanqunzi maybe because `Base` has no function called `+=`? You could write `*(static_cast<Base*>(this)) += rhs;` but I don't think it's better :)